# Syntax error near unexpected token fi

Tags: bash, shell

```
#export usage='Usage: sh applyPatches4fa_allcases.sh <Parameter Properties File Name>'
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
echo "The parameters are incorrectly passed"
echo $usage
echo $usageexample
exit 1
fi
if test -f $1  
then
 echo $1 'file exist'
else
echo $1 'file does not exist'
exit 1
fi
logfile=applyPatches4fa.log;
if [ -f "$logfile" ]; then
 rm -f $logfile;
else
touch -a $logfile;
fi
```

The above code is in my applyPathes.sh file and below i ran the command on console
sh applyPatches.sh ok.sql

I got below output

```
ok.sql file exist
line 20: syntex error near unexpected token fi
```

Comment: Please post “your applyPathes.sh”. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: And please use copy & paste for error messages. It definitely says “syntax” instead of “syntex”.

Comment: Read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Keep the original question **and** include the code. And do a proper copy-paste of the code!

Comment: To add a file, just go to your editor, select all, copy, then go and edit your question and paste the code. You should take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), including the SO editor help pages (see that question-mark in the toolbar when you edit your question?)

Comment: how to attach file ? can u please help me out on this?

Comment: i want to attach code file but i dont find any option to attach it... can you please help me out on this?

Comment: You don't "attach" a file, you simply paste the code into the editor on the web-page. You *do* know how to copy-paste text?

Comment: Okay, now which line is line 20? The one the error complain about?

Comment: Works fine for me when trying it out. Is the script in your question the *complete* script? Does it do something *after* the code you posted.

Comment: This is complete code... i am shocked about why it is not running in my machine... can you help me on this.. plz..

Comment: Then there's something else wrong, something you haven't told or show us. Because the script as it is in the question runs fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The code runs for me so you probably forgot to end the file with a newline, therefore the last line (with the fi) is not executed.

Comment: Should not matter, and works for me (yes anecdotal I know) both with and without the last newline.

Comment: Your system may be forgiving, but ending a bash script without newline as the last character has been more often than induced the behaviour I described. I want the reaction of the OP on this just to make sure (btw check your file with a hex editor, maybe your texteditor inserted the last newline for you)